# select() transformed/new variables inside one mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider a df like this:

```
   colA colB colC colD
1     1   50  100    a
2     2   51  101    b
3     3   52  102    c
4     4   53  103    d
5     5   54  104    e
6     6   55  105    f
7     7   56  106    g
8     8   57  107    h
9     9   58  108    i
10   10   59  109    j
```

I want to transform the variable "colA" and then calculate a row sum of variables which I choose by `select()` inside `mutate()`. I'm doing this:

```
df %>%
 mutate(colA = colA * 60,
        sum = rowSums(select(., colA, colB, colC)))
```

which gives me an incorrect result:

```
   colA colB colC colD sum
1    60   50  100    a 151
2   120   51  101    b 154
3   180   52  102    c 157
4   240   53  103    d 160
5   300   54  104    e 163
6   360   55  105    f 166
7   420   56  106    g 169
8   480   57  107    h 172
9   540   58  108    i 175
10  600   59  109    j 178
```

If I create an entirely new variable:

```
df %>%
 mutate(colA_mod = colA * 60,
        sum = rowSums(select(., colA_mod, colB, colC)))
```

I get:

> Error: Evaluation error: Position must be between 0 and n.

However, when I use two separate `mutate()`s, I'm getting the right results:

```
df %>%
 mutate(colA = colA * 60) %>%
 mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., colA, colB, colC)))

   colA colB colC colD sum
1    60   50  100    a 210
2   120   51  101    b 272
3   180   52  102    c 334
4   240   53  103    d 396
5   300   54  104    e 458
6   360   55  105    f 520
7   420   56  106    g 582
8   480   57  107    h 644
9   540   58  108    i 706
10  600   59  109    j 768
```

So the question is, how I can transform a variable/create a new variable and select it inside one `mutate()`?

**Sample data**:

```
df <- data.frame(colA = 1:10,
colB = 50:59,
colC = 100:109,
colD = letters[1:10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible with `cur_data()` in `dplyr` > 1.0.0

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(colA = colA * 60,
         sum = rowSums(select(cur_data(), colA, colB, colC)))

#   colA colB colC colD sum
#1    60   50  100    a 210
#2   120   51  101    b 272
#3   180   52  102    c 334
#4   240   53  103    d 396
#5   300   54  104    e 458
#6   360   55  105    f 520
#7   420   56  106    g 582
#8   480   57  107    h 644
#9   540   58  108    i 706
#10  600   59  109    j 768
```

---

**Earlier Answer**

One option is to add `colA` separately

```
df %>%
  mutate(colA = colA * 60,
         sum = rowSums(select(., colB, colC)) + colA)


#   colA colB colC colD sum
#1    60   50  100    a 210
#2   120   51  101    b 272
#3   180   52  102    c 334
#4   240   53  103    d 396
#5   300   54  104    e 458
#6   360   55  105    f 520
#7   420   56  106    g 582
#8   480   57  107    h 644
#9   540   58  108    i 706
#10  600   59  109    j 768
```

When you are using `select(., colA, colB, colC)`, `.` is the orignal dataframe and the columns selected are from the original dataframe as well. Hence, it does not have information about updated values of `colA`. That is the same reason why you get the error in your 2nd attempt

```
rowSums(select(., colA_mod, colB, colC))
```

as `colA_mod` column is not part of the original dataframe (`df`).

Comment: Very elegant possibility! However, I'm still curious whether there is a way to somehow update the original df that is referenced by `.` in `select()`.

Comment: @tmfmnk This now works with `cur_data()`.

Comment: This is very nice, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Switching out `rowSums` and `select` will get the job done:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(colA = colA * 60,
          sum = colA + colB + colC)
```

If you have NAs first turn them into zero so it behaves like and na.rm:

```
df %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(colA = colA * 60,
         sum = colA + colB + colC)
```

Alternatively here's a solution that allows `rowSums` and one mutate:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., colA:colC) * 
    matrix(rep(c(60,1,1), times = 10), byrow = T, ncol = 3), na.rm = T))
```

Outputting:

```
   colA colB colC colD sum
1     1   50  100    a 210
2     2   NA  101    b 221
3     3   52  102    c 334
4     4   53  103    d 396
5     5   54  104    e 458
6     6   55  105    f 520
7     7   56  106    g 582
8     8   57  107    h 644
9     9   58  108    i 706
10   10   59  109    j 768
```

Comment: It could be a possibility, however, in my real data I also have NAs. It is much more handy to add `na.rm = TRUE` into `rowSums()`.

Comment: @tmfmnk found a solution that allows rowSums

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is a placeholder for what was sent into the pipe. In this case, your mutation of `colA` does not update what's in the pipeline in the `mutate` call.

You can add another pipe:

```
df %>%
  mutate(colA = colA * 60)%>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., colA, colB, colC)))
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I also included this possibility in my question :) Moreover, I really want to do it in one `mutate()`.

Comment: Oops. Basically, though, you can't do what you want. The ```.``` won't update until the next pipe forward ```%>%```.